# Is it possible to use variables as dom elements?

Tags: javascript

I have a several input fields in a form each having a unique name. For example, to change the color I would do:

```
testForm.username.style.background = "yellow";
```

`username` being the name of the input and `testform` being the form name

I want to do this: replace `username` with a variable `elem` so that when I call the function to change the background color I don't need to have a separate function for every unique field. I would just send the `elem` name and that function would work for every field.

```
testForm.elem.style.background = "yellow";
```

My problem is it doesn't work. For example it passed the `elem` into the function fine, but it says that `testForm.elem.style` is `null`. For some reason javascript doesn't like variables for element names I'm guessing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var elem = 'username';
testForm[elem].style.background = 'yellow';
```

Comment: Not a good idea. Accessing it off of an `elements` collections would be more reliable and standard-compliant, e.g.: `testForm.elements[elem].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'`

Comment: RaYell thanks for the help, it worked just like I wanted it to. I was under the impression that testForm[elem].style was the same as testForm.elem.style... guess not!

What is the advantage of using the elements collection? How does it help me other than being standard compliant?

Comment: I would also test for existence of an element (and its `style` property) before attempting to modify it - `var el = testForm.elements[elem]; if (el && el.style) el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
testForm [elem].style.background = "yellow";
```

or

```
var elem = testForm.username
elem.style.background = "yellow";
```

in the first case `elem` holds the username, and in the second case, `elem` points to the actual DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

A property of a JavaScript object (in this case, the "username" property of the object "testform") can be accessed using either `object.property` or `object["property"]` syntax. As the second form takes a string (as shown by the double quotes), it follows that a variable containing a string can also be used with that syntax. Hence:

```
testform[elem].style.background = "yellow";
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're creating a function to do this anyway.  In that case, why not just use the following function:

```
function changeBackgroundOfElementToYellow(element){
  element.style.background = "yellow";
}
```

And call it with:

```
changeBackgroundofElementToYellow(testForm.username);
```

In general I find the RaYell/kangax method posted already to be better, but this is another option.

Answer (score -3):

You'd have to do an eval to do something like that, eg eval("testform." + elem + ".style.background=yellow");

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, it will only give you a headache. Check this out http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#evil